# StringBuilder vs. StringBuffer - mnemonic wanted

Tags: java, stringbuilder, stringbuffer

I know the technical differences between [`StringBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) and [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html).

But if I don't use them for half a year or so, I just forget which one is synchronized and which one is not. I always have lookup the first sentence of the JavaDoc.

So: Is there some kind of easy to remember mnemonic to distinguish them? How do *YOU* remember the difference?

Comment: Write more code...

Comment: I'm guessing you struggle with that whole "Where did I put my keys" thing in the morning as well?

Comment: @Andrew *LOL* Both together form a nice and funny picture :-) Would you please write it as an answer? (For bonus points.)

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I do, but these kind of stuff usually ends very soon in some kind of framework which is used then.

Comment: I duno if I should try to build my SO rep on my poetry. They'd prolly ban me and rightly so!

Comment: The truth is that most of the time, it doesn't matter and if you don't use them often, I wouldn't worry about it.  Even though the Javadoc suggest using StringBuilder, StringBuffer appears in the  JDK libraries almost 3x as often as StringBuilder even though thread safety is not needed. e.g. It is used in StringDateFormat even though its not a thread safe class. ;)

Comment: You could implement your own class let's call it `AHStringBuilder` by plagarizing `StringBuilder`.  Or better yet `AHStringBuilderFactory` which always returns a `java.lang.StringBuilder`.  Either way you don't have to remember anything.

Comment: My point is that even though StringBuilder has been recommended for 8 years, most of the JDK hasn't been migrated even though its a drop in replacement. i.e. a global find and replace would do the job. (It just doesn't matter enough, most of the time)

Answer (score 5):

**1**
StringBuffer is older implementation. Older implementations of collections were also synchronized.

Now how to remember that buffer is older than builder? Think, how would you call class that is able to contain buffer of characters that can be transformed to string? The answer is `StringBuffer`. This is what the guys from Sun Microsystem thought when they initially developed this class.

Then they wanted to find yet another name for almost the same thing and remembered that it actually implements `Builder` pattern. Pattern became more fashionable later, so they called the new class Builder.

I hope this helps.

**2**
Other mnemonics. Compare the workds:
Buffer
Builder

The difference is in the3 3rd letter that is the first letter of word "first". It means that buffer was *first*

**3** 
Just sort these 2 words alphabetically: Buffer, Builder. Buffer is first, builder is second. Therefore buffer is synchronized (see the beginning of my story)

Comment: I like the first one, that buffer is more fundamental (and thus old), then comes the builder pattern.

Answer (score 1):

New asynchronous classes have more natural names, I think. `List`, a well defined computer scientific concept, instead of `Vector`. `Map`, a well defined mathematical concept, instead of `Table`. `Builder`, a common name for a factory class, instead of `Buffer`.

It works for me!